# Coudn't Find Use Of Acces-Token While Creating Contacts In Outlook Account

Tags: php, curl, ms-office, exchangewebservices, access-token

So I am trying to create contacts into the outlook account I read a lot of documentation but I couldn't find where to use generated access-token.

This is Sample API Request to Create contacts to Outlook account

```
 POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts
 Content-Type: application/json
 {
 "GivenName": "Pavel",
 "Surname": "Bansky",
 "EmailAddresses": 
 [
 {
  "Address": "pavelb@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
  "Name": "Pavel Bansky"
 }
 ],
 "BusinessPhones": [
 "+1 732 555 0102"
]
}
```

also If somebody tells me how to use curl post request to create contacts to outlook account that would help me a lot.

ok this is my curl operations

```
   $api_url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts";
    $curl = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$_SESSION['ToKen_office']));
  //  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:   application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JsonEncodedData); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl_Response = curl_exec($curl);
    $header = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($curl_Response, 0, $header);
    var_dump($header);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I am getting below error

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
 request-id: 274b87cc-7bf9-4dbb-8ae5-d124251a15eb
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 X-FEServer: MA1PR01CA0090
 X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 9F0639FDFB244DBA9FC977E6C446B7DC Ref B: MAA01EDGE0122 
 Ref C: 2018-03-23T10:46:04Z
 Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 10:46:04 GMT
 Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: you should check the API documentation more thoroughly, because it should be explained somewhere, but usually has to be sent inside an "Authorisation" HTTP header, not as part of the request body.

Comment: Yes you are right we have to add it to a header but I am getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error

Comment: Should I edit my question with curl code?

Comment: That would be a good idea, yes. You can also debug your request yourself using a tool such as Fiddler to monitor your network traffic, then you can see the HTTP request which your cURL code constructed, and check whether it's structured in the way you expected. Alteratively you can approach it from the other direction - use a tool such as PostMan to construct your request by hand until it's correct, and then it contains tools which will convert your request into code using cURL and other tools.

Comment: Actually I am using rest API for debugging but couldn't find where is the problem

Comment: "I am using rest API for debugging"...a rest API is a design concept not a debugging tool. What are you actually using?

Comment: To begin the most basic task though, have you verified in your debugging that `$_SESSION['ToKen_office']` actually contains a valid token when your code executes?

Comment: Yes, My whole code is in if Condition it's checking access-token is empty or not also verified it is valid or not

Comment: just because it exists doesn't mean it's a valid token.

Comment: Yes, I am verifying it I am comparing original token and session token if it is true then it will call that curl operations

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Pass it In Header

```
$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer ". $Your_Access-Token,
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-type: application/json",
"odata.metadata: full",
"client-request-id: ".$Your_Client_ID,
"return-client-request-id: FALSE",
"X-AnchorMailbox: ".$EmailId_Of_Account_Where_You_Want_To_Push_Contacts
);
```

CURL Operation

```
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```